Examples of anti-classical theories in iFOL
An anti-classical axiom $\phi$ is one which is inconsistent with LEM
Are there any sources for good examples of anti-classical theories in intuitionstic first-order logic? There are many examples of topoi with anti-classical properties (such as "all functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ are computable"), but I'm unable to find many simple first-order theories.
One which we can devise is the theory of the non-trivial tiny object:
(with no extra symbols besides equality)
$$
\forall xy, \neg\neg(x = y)\\
\neg \forall xy, (x=y)
$$
This is inspired by the set of infinitesimals in SDG.
Are all anti-classical theories of a sort like this? I suppose equality could be replaced with any relational symbol.

"a sort like this" sounds a bit ambiguous making the answer hard to state. What do you mean for that? Also, the previous version of your question seems to suggest you are only considering Grothendieck toposes, but there are non-classical elementary toposes (like, realizability toposes)

"A sort like this" meaning of the form: adding some relation-symbol and exploiting a similar condition on quantifiers. This is a question about the theory, not the models, so I'm not sure the question about Grothendieck vs. non-Grothendieck is relevant. AFAIK there's a completeness theorem that Grothendieck topoi always suffice (take the syntactic topos)

Also I do not think every anti-intuitionistic theory satisfies what you mentioned; For example, $\mathsf{HA}$ proves LEM for $\Delta_0$-formulas, so for every binary predicate symbol $R$ in the language of $\mathsf{HA}$ (either ${<,=}$ or the set of all primitive recursive binary relations) we have $\lnot\lnot R(x,y)\to R(x,y)$. In particular, it is impossible that both $\forall x,y \lnot\lnot R(x,y)$ and $\lnot \forall x,y R(x,y)$ hold for an atomic binary predicate $R$. However, there are non-classical models of $\mathsf{HA}$...

Yes, not all theories extend this. This is a distinct theory from the theory of Heyting Arithmetic. It is already inconsistent because HA proves that $0 \not = 1$, regardless of the proofs of LEM, but that's inconsistent with $\forall x y, \neg (x \neq y)$

I adjusted the question to clarify what anti-classical means here. It is different from non-classical (i.e. not-necessarily-classical)

Since you are careful about first-order vs. higher-order, what is $LEM$ in $\phi \land LEM \vdash \bot$? In first-order logic LEM would be a schema, not a formula, but then your characterization of anti-classical is not well formed. Wouldn't it be better to just say that a theory (as opposed to an axiom) is anti-classical if it proves $\neg (\phi \lor \neg \phi)$ for at least one formula $\phi$?

Also, you should allow multi-sorted theories here, because in intuitionsitic logic we cannot play tricks that reduce multi-sorted theories to single-sorted ones.

@AndrejBauer A theory that proves $\neg(\phi\lor\neg\phi)$ is not just anti-classical, but inconsistent. Anyway, I think the intent is clear: a formula $\phi$, or a theory $T$ if you wish, is anticlassical if it is inconsistent with classical logic, i.e., if $\mathrm{LEM}\cup T\vdash\bot$ to use a more formally correct notation. This amounts to $T\vdash\neg\bigwedge_{i<n}\forall\vec x,(\phi_i(\vec x)\lor\neg\phi_i(\vec x))$ for some formulas $\phi_i$.

I was about to ask exactly that question. I reworded it to be vaguer so as to be correct, but we definitely need to use formulas with free variables, and was wondering if  it suffices to only use one formula or possibly multiple

Oops, a rookie mistake! Anyhow, it does seem difficult to come by reasonable anti-classical first-order theories. Interesting.

On second thoughts, just $n=1$ suffices, i.e., a theory is anticlassical iff it proves $\neg\forall\vec x,(\phi(\vec x)\lor\neg\phi(\vec x))$ for some formula $\phi(\vec x)$. The reduction from the form above is to take for $\phi(\vec x)$ the formula $\bigwedge_i(\phi_i(\vec x)\lor\neg\phi_i(\vec x))$ (whose negation is provably false).

A non-artificial example of an anticlassical theory is HA + CT (or its extentions like ECT).

But I think ECT wouldn't count according to the OP since it quantifies over functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, would it?

Allegedly there are some extensions like: $\textbf{HA} + \neg \forall n, (P(n) \vee \neg P(n))$ which are consistent (and anti-classical), but I haven't found details for these yet.
Interestingly the form of this is quite similar to the example above (since $\forall n, \neg\neg (P(n) \vee \neg P(n))$ is trivially true)

@AndrejBauer I'm sure higher-order people use it in ways I am not familiar with, but in the context of first-order arithmetic, no, ECT is just a first-order axiom schema: $\forall x,(\psi(x)\to\exists y,\phi(x,y))\to\exists e,\forall x,(\psi(x)\to\exists y,({e}(x)\simeq y\land\phi(x,y)))$, where $\psi$ is essentially negative, and ${e}(x)\simeq y$ denotes a $\Sigma_1$ formula expressing "the program with code $e$ computes $y$ on input $x$".

@JasonCarr Sure, as mentioned above, CT (which is a schema like the ECT written above, but without $\psi$) implies this e.g. when $P$ is a $\Sigma_1$-complete predicate such as ${e}(x)\simeq y$ (encode the triple $\langle e,x,y\rangle$ with a single number $n$ if you wish).

@EmilJeřábek: It would be worth posting ECT (phrased as a schema) as an answer, I think.

@AndrejBauer Regarding many-sorted theories, for theories with finitely many sorts, don't the standard classical model theory tricks of coding functions as relations and coding sorts as disjoint (decidable) sets still work intuitionistically? In other words, isn't it still true that every theory with finitely many sorts is biinterpretable with a single-sorted (relational) theory? What tricks don't work exactly?

@EmilJeřábek "A theory that proves ¬(ϕ∨¬ϕ) is not just anti-classical, but inconsistent." How so?

@user76284 Intuitionistic logic proves $\neg\neg(\phi\lor\neg\phi)$.

@EmilJeřábek I see: ¬(ϕ∨¬ϕ) ⇒ (ϕ∨¬ϕ)→⊥ ⇒ (ϕ→⊥)∧(¬ϕ→⊥) ⇒ (ϕ→⊥)∧((ϕ→⊥)→⊥) ⇒ ⊥.

One example of an anti-classical theory that’s not artificially constructed for that purpose is $\mathsf{HA+CT_0}$, where the Church–Turing thesis $\mathsf{CT_0}$ is the schema
$$\forall x\:\exists y\:\phi(x,y)\to\exists e\:\forall x\:\exists y\:\bigl(\{e\}(x)\simeq y\land\phi(x,y)\bigr).$$
Here, $\{e\}(x)\simeq y$ denotes a $\Sigma_1$ formula formalizing the predicate “the program with code $e$ computes output $y$ on input $x$”, and $\phi$ may have other parameters besides $x$ and $y$. This contradicts classical logic, as $\mathsf{PA}$ proves the existence of noncomputable definable functions.
More generally, there is the extended Church–Turing thesis $\mathsf{ECT_0}$,
$$\forall x\:\bigl(\psi(x)\to\exists y\:\phi(x,y)\bigr)\to\exists e\:\forall x\:\bigl(\psi(x)\to\exists y\:\bigl(\{e\}(x)\simeq y\land\phi(x,y)\bigr)\bigr),$$
where $\psi(x)$ is an almost negative formula (a formula constructed from $\Sigma_1$ formulas using $\to$, $\land$, and $\forall$, again with possibly other free variables). The theory $\mathsf{HA+ECT_0}$ is important due to its connections to Kleene realizability.
But concerning Are all anti-classical theories of a sort like this?—in a way, yes. Let me elaborate the characterization of anti-classical theories from the comments. Given a (first-order intuitionistic) theory $T$, and a formula $\phi$, let $T\vdash_i\phi$ denote that $T$ proves $\phi$ over intuitionistic logic, and $T\vdash_c\phi$ that $T$ proves $\phi$ over classical logic. First, we have:

Lemma. $T\vdash_c\phi$ iff there is a formula $\psi(\vec x)$ such that $T\vdash_i\forall\vec x\,(\psi(\vec x)\lor\neg\psi(\vec x))\to\phi$.

Proof: The right-to-left implication is trivial. For the left-to-right implication, let $\pi$ be a classical Hilbert-style proof of $\phi$ from $T$. Then $\pi$ is an intuitionistic proof of $\phi$ from $T$ and from some instances $\{\psi_i(\vec x)\lor\neg\psi_i(\vec x):i<n\}$ of LEM (here $\vec x$ is a list including all free variables of all the $\psi_i$). Put
$$\psi(\vec x)=\bigwedge_{i<n}(\psi_i(\vec x)\lor\neg\psi_i(\vec x)).$$
Since $\vdash_i\neg\neg\psi(\vec x)$, the formula $\psi(\vec x)\lor\neg\psi(\vec x)$ is equivalent to $\psi(\vec x)$ itself, which obviously implies each $\psi_i(\vec x)\lor\neg\psi_i(\vec x)$. Thus, passing also to a universal closure, we get
$$T+\forall\vec x\:(\psi(\vec x)\lor\neg\psi(\vec x))\vdash_i\phi.$$
Then the result follows by the deduction theorem. QED

Corollary. For a given theory $T$, the following are equivalent:

$T\vdash_c\bot$ (i.e., $T$ is anti-classical).

$T\vdash_i\neg\forall\vec x\,(\psi(\vec x)\lor\neg\psi(\vec x))$ for some formula $\psi$.

$T\vdash_i\forall\vec x\,\neg\neg\psi(\vec x)$ and $T\vdash_i\neg\forall\vec x\,\psi(\vec x)$ for some formula $\psi$.



Proof: 1 → 2 follows from the Lemma, 2 → 3 from $\vdash_i\forall\vec x\,\neg\neg(\psi(\vec x)\lor\neg\psi(\vec x))$, and 3 → 1 is clear.
An interesting consequence of this is that an intuitionistic theory is consistent with classical logic iff it is consistent with the double-negation shift schema
$$\tag{DNS}\forall x\:\neg\neg\phi(x)\to\neg\neg\forall x\:\phi(x),$$
even though the latter is strictly weaker than classical logic. (Even better, DNS can be characterized as the weakest extension of intuitionistic first-order logic with this property: that is, whenever $T$ is a theory such that all consistent extensions of $T$ are consistent with classical logic, then $T$ proves DNS.)

It took me a second to see why this schema is anti-classical. Since all intuitionistically definable functions can truly be computed by a Turing machine regardless of the presence of LEM, it would seem that each instance would be fine and so the whole would be.
So the interesting character is in the $\forall x, \exists y, \phi(x, y) \to ...$ portion, for specific formulae. And so rather it's a direct assertion of the non-existence of such a proof for non-computable functions $\neg \forall x, \exists y, \phi(x,y)$. The contrapositive feels more enlightening here.

Also: are there other original sources for the claims in the second half of this answer? Of course they're brief enough to understand here, but I was curious how much this topic has been addressed before

I don't know. It sounds like a basic thing that was probably observed before, but to be honest, I'm not well read in literature on intuitionistic logic.
